# How to render a list/stringbuilder to template

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I have a list of objects that i retrieved from a JSon File. I am trying to render them into the index.scala.html to create a table, but I am unable to do so. Help?

I tried `@(StringBuilder: mystring)` and it did not work.

I was wondering after I am successful (hopefully) in rendering the list/stringbuilder into the template how do I use it to make a table?

```
public static Result index() {
  List<MetaModel> arr = getData();

  StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder();
  for(MetaModel model : arr)
  {
    myString.append(model.toString());
  }

  return ok(index.render(myString.toString()));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Java is a bit rusty, anyway you are calling `toString()` on the `StringBuilder` but in the template you have `@(StringBuilder: mystring)` which is the wrong type and the wrong syntax, it should be `@(myString: String)`.

If instead you want to pass the `StringBuilder` to the template, simply avoid calling `toString` and bind the variable like this `@(mystring: StringBuilder)`.

For `List`s, simply bind the variable in the template `@(integers: List[Int])` and then use `map`

```
<ul>
  @integers.map { someInt => <li>@someInt</li> }
</ul>
```

or simpler `@for` function:

```
<ul>
   @for( someInt <- integers) { <li>@someInt</li> }
</ul>
```

More info and also some examples are also on the [Play documentation for Java](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaTemplates).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, To receive the data in template, data type should always be declared after creating the variable. It should be **@(myString : StringBuilder)**.
Secondly, you have send wrong data type to the template. you have send the data of type **String** but you are trying to receive the data of type **StringBuilder**